# RGB to CMYK in Gimp, what i'm doing wrong?

Tags: colors, gimp, rgb, cmyk

I'm trying to convert image from RGB to CMYK in Gimp, tried to search for answers, but couldn't fine one that would work for me, or I missed something important.

My preferences of color management are:

[image]

I have one image, that has a lot of light-green areas indicating that they are outside of my CMYK profile. So I went Image->Separate->Separate. And used those settings:

[image]

It produced image with four channels - C+M+Y+K. Good. Next: Image->Separate->Proof. Settings:

[image]

Produced image have different colors, but I still can see a lot of green areas. How the hell does it work? :D Using Image->Separate->Export and exporting to tiff with embedded Euroscale Coated v2 profile, has the same effect - colors are different, but it still looks like is outside of my target profile. What I'm doing wrong?

Regards.

**Also:**
When I'm saving supposed CMYK image as TIFF (exporting from Separate), and embedding profile, when I open it, box shows up and says that the image has an embedded profile: sRGB build-in (???) even If I chose to embed other profile. I don't understand it :/ .